# MVC model with sorting and filtering logic

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt

I was wondering where I should put logic for sorting and filtering a Qt tables in a MVC model. I'm working with a `QAbstractTableModel`.

- My tables are handling anywhere from 20 items to 100,000.
- I need to handle multiple views of the same data with different sort and filter criteria.

I'm relatively new to the MVC model so bear with me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sorting/filtering is specific to a view, then the filtering/sorting logic belongs in the View.

Edit: I suppose I should add that the logic itself doesn't necessarily belong in the view -- depending on the situation, you might (for example) have a back-end that uses something like SQL, in which case the query that specifies the filtering/sorting goes in the view, but the implementation of the sorting/filtering itself would end up in SQL implementation. Even if you use something less elaborate than SQL, you can still have a generic implementation of the logic in the back-end, and only a specification of what to do in the view itself.